Automating creating accounts EHR/EMR (like EPIC/Cerner/Athenhealth) using APIs
The normal way of integrating with EHR/EMR instances is that you have:

Create an account.
Build your app.
Get client IDs, and use their APIs to get data.
Test in sandbox mode.
Move to production.
Contact other facilities if you want to get their patients' data.

That's how EPIC, Cerner, and AthenaHealth are normally connected/integrated.
Now, I need to automate this whole process so that I won't have to go to each EHR to create an account and repeat the entire process for each one of them.
Is there any way, or APIs available where I can create the developer account and get the API keys, etc., and then list other community members of a respective EHR, and request access/integration?

Nothing like this exists today, and it's doubtful anything like it would be available in the future. Creating, testing, and deploying an app is a critical series of steps where you want to ensure you're doing it correctly and accurately, such as selecting only the minimum necessary API calls for your integration. Often you need to complete an acknowledgement that you've tested accurately prior to deploying to production.
